# Can't find basic activity template in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, templates

I am a beginner programmer. I was following a tutorial and it used basic activity template, but I can't find it. Is there a place to download it or a way to make it available in Android Studio?

I am using Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 patch 1

I have tried downloading 2021 version and I have found the basic activity but it had too many Gradle issues/system errors that I can't seem to solve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Empty Views Activity" in Giraffe instead of the "Basic Activity" template in older versions, both are the same.

Comment: but in the Mainactivity the code is completely different

Comment: @JAT06 I guess your tutorial is teaching Android with Java language. right?
if you are not sure you can see the file name so if the file name of MainActivity in the tutorial is .java so you are following an old tutorial otherwise please tell me what is the difference between your MainActivity file and the one in tutorial?

Comment: i am using coursera meta android app development course it uses kotlin my main activity file is under the com.example under java file its completely different code than the one that appeared in the video

Comment: @JAT06 Please tell me some of these differences.

Comment: one of the main differences is there is completely different code written, like there is 40+ lines of code in basic activity but empty i think 14 lines or a bit more i know they may have like written the same meaning of code but in less lines but as i am following the course its a bit confusing

Comment: @JAT06 can you see some lines of code which use `binding`? 
anyway you have two ways: 
1. start watching the tutorial and the teacher definitely teach what is that and how you can write them.
 
2. find a newer course to learn 'Jetpack compose' which is recommended by  Google instead of previous approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is the option that you are looking for. You need to select `Basic Views Activity` from the templates. The code for this will likely be a bit different than what the tutorial has. You might need to modify a few things in your Java/Kotlin code and in your XML. If you need any further help, we can continue this discussion in chat.

[image: Screenshot]